# How to use group in grep regex?

Tags: regex, grep

How to write a regex in grep command to have something like:

```
grep '[(group1)(group2)]' <file>
```

I'd like to find the lines in file that matches group1 or group2 in .

Comment: `grep 'group1\|group2' <file>`

Comment: @anubhava: Perhaps post as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -E 'group1|group2' file
```

or:

```
grep -e 'group1' -e 'group2' file
```